# Invoking a Select HTML Element OnChange Event from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement that when I click a DIV I should trigger the Select HTML Element onChange event.

```
<select name="SWF_2_FauxColors_Reg" onchange="show_product_1(this)" />
```

I can access the select from inside the DIV event but when I do the following:

```
var select = $(this); // where $(this) is a select html list 

myDiv.click(function(){

            select.val($(this).attr("id")).change();


        });
```

But the above does not trigger the show_product_1(this) event. I cannot call the show_product_1(this) directly since it is dynamically inserted into the select html list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jquery [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function:

```
 select.trigger("onchange");
```

Comment: Thanks but nothing happens!

Comment: I had to invoke onchange in the trigger and it worked! Thanks!